# Excel VLookup VBA cant refer to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

```
Public Function Lohn(ID)

Lohn = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ID, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arbeiter").Range("A:D"), 2, 0)

End Function
```

I cant access the Worksheet "Arbeiter" its just doesn't give me a Value back can some one help me

There is nothing more code in the Section if anyone wants to know
ID is numeric

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try calling your function from a Sub instead of from a worksheet, and see what error you get.

Comment: or put: `? Lohn(1)` in the immediate window.

Comment: Is your function placed in a module?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work after changing from Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup to Application.VLookup

Be careful to load in an ID with the same data type as the value in the cell. It gave me error 2042 when i used a string as the ID but was able to work properly when I put in an integer.

Here is your function after my changes:

```
Public Function Lohn(ID)

Lohn = Application.VLookup(ID, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arbeiter").Range("A:D"), 2, False)

End Function
```